# Function set to run once not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Happy Holidays! How do i get this function running? I can see the console.log running on the mouse wheel, however the function set to run once does not run. On the start i have also made sure that the body contains both the required classes.

```
var $body = $('body');
            //using index
            if(index == 2){
                $body.css({
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                });

                if($body.hasClass('fp-viewing-secondPage')) {
                        $('html').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
                            console.log('fucks');
                            var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                            if($body.hasClass('setAn1')){
                                var something = (function() {
                                    var secret = false;
                                    return function () {
                                        if(!secret){
                                            console.log('call me once please an1');
                                            secret = true;
                                        }
                                    };
                                });
                                something();
                            }
                            if($body.hasClass('setAn2')){
                                var something2 = (function() {
                                    var secret = false;
                                    return function () {
                                        if(!secret){
                                            console.log('call me once please an2');
                                            secret = true;
                                        }
                                    };
                                });
                                something2();
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you ever call the function?

Comment: Is `$body` defined ?

Comment: From the first function (the one that is assigned to something) you are returning another function that is never executed. If you want to execute both functions add another `()` after the ones that you already have, or just call `something()`

Comment: Don't know if this helps or what version js you are using. Try looking into .one()

Comment: Here's a link to what I'm talking about, it's in jquery: http://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var something = (function() {
    var secret = false;
    return function () {
        if(!secret) {
            console.log('call me once please an1');
            secret = true;
        }
    };
})();
```

You have the above block which is an IIFE. I believe what it's doing is assigning the below function to the something variable.

```
function () {
    if(!secret) {
        console.log('call me once please an1');
        secret = true;
    }
```

You'd have to then call the something() here.

```
                secret = true;
            }
        };
    })();
   something();
}
```

I ported the structure of your program over into jfiddle. Your primary problem is that you're modifying a value who was defined inside of the scope created by the definition of the function. This value only lasts as long as that function is currently executing, once you leave the function the value leaves scope. What you need to do is define the variable outside the scope of the function so that you won't lose the state you're trying to keep between clicks.

Here's a minimal example. You'll see the secret gets set once you go through the loop, and then prevents the function's if() condition from being evaluated again.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

var secret = false;
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('what is my secret outside?', secret);
  if (!secret) {
    console.log('what is my secret inside?', secret);
    secret = true;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wa819y2j/9/

Comment: I changed it. and now the function is being called however its not firing only once but multiple times. How do i reconfigure the code for single use?

Comment: @RickiMoore each time you're doing the assignment, your also calling the outer function, and creating a new context and a new secret variable. So yes, if you call it right after the assignment, it the console.log statement will be executed each time.

Comment: Thanks @MauricePerry, so how do i structure this so it will call once? Im lost on that part.

Comment: @RickiMoore I updated the answer. I don't think there's any reason you need that IIFE in the middle of your code.

Comment: @RickiMoore it depends. If you want it run once for the whole lifespan of your script, you should declare and assign something and something2 at the top-level of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
var something = (function() {
    var secret = false;
    return function () {
        if(!secret){
            console.log('call me once please an1');
            secret = true;
        }
    };
});
var something2 = (function() {
    var secret = false;
    return function () {
        if(!secret){
            console.log('call me once please an2');
            secret = true;
        }
    };
});

var $body = $('body');
            //using index
            if(index == 2){
                $body.css({
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                });

                if($body.hasClass('fp-viewing-secondPage')) {
                        $('html').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
                            console.log('fucks');
                            var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                            if($body.hasClass('setAn1')){
                                something();
                            }
                            if($body.hasClass('setAn2')){
                                something2();
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
```

Or else:

```
function runOnce(fun) {
    var secret = false;
    return function () {
        if(!secret){
            fun();
            secret = true;
        }
    };
}

var something = runOnce(function() {
    console.log('call me once please an1');
});
var something2 = runOnce(function() {
    console.log('call me once please an2');
});
```